# fatal: unable to get credential storage lock: Permission denied

Tags: windows, git

When I try to use `git pull` or any other command that needs credentials I get asked for them:

```
Username for 'https://git.private.com': test
Password for 'https://test@git.private.com':
fatal: unable to get credential storage lock: Permission denied
```

But they are not saved - where can I find the credentials file and delete it? It is not in my home dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, git tried to access the .gitconfig of WSL. So I disconnected the mounted virtual disk for WSL and tried again - everything worked flawlessly.

Maybe this will help someone...